# Cursor issue while entering date manually

Tags: input, kendo-ui, position, cursor

I am using Kendo date picker when i change already selected date manually then every time when i enter number cursor moves to end of date. Is there any way for this.

I am using input tag for date picker.

Comment: Are you using numbers at numpad? enable numlock key, otherwise show code

Comment: My html code: <input onkeydown="formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy');" id="start" class="searchdatepicker" kendo-date-picker>

Comment: What is `formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy');`? Please update the question with full code that respond to datepicker behavior

Comment: formatDate() is a function used by kendo ui for formatting datepicker.